# Is there any way to obtain an approximate/optimal real solution to a quadratic equation that has a complex solution?

Tags: optimization, approximation, quadratics

Assume that for the quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ there is no real solution ($\Delta = b^2 - 4ac < 0$). Is there a way to obtain an approximate real solution? i.e. some optimization technique.

*Context* - this is part of an algorithm I'm developing for a measurement system. Theoretically, the solution would always be real ($ \Delta \geq 0$); however, due to measurement errors this is not always the case. In most of these cases $\Delta$ is very close to zero.

Would assuming that $\Delta$ actually is equal to zero be the best possible approximation?

Comment: I'm sorry but how could you expect to approximate a complex solution to a real one? o.O

Comment: Would you be interested in finding an $x$ that minimizes $| ax^{2}+bx+c |$?

Comment: @Brian Borchers, I didn't really think about it that way, but now that you mention it I think that's really what I would need. So I guess I should just find the local minimum? i.e. $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$.

Comment: @FourierTransform complex numbers always confuse me. When I was posting the question I didn't actually stop to think through what it means to have no real solution (i.e. a parabola entirely above or below the $x$ axis). Thanks.

Comment: @Hadi if there's no real root, then either $x=-b/2a$ is the minimizer of $ax^{2}+bx+c$ and all valuers are greater than 0, or $x=-b/2a$ is the maximizer and all values are less than 0.  By the way, which root do you want if there are two real roots?

Comment: I've developed a relationship for choosing the correct root if there are two. It's based on some (physical) constraints on the coefficients in my specific application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for the smallest absolute value of the quadratic, then you're looking for the vertex, which conveniently always occurs at $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$, with appropriate y-value.